# How to define a group ring when the group is infinte?

Tags: modules, group-rings

I am trying to prove the following from Tadao Oda's "Convex bodies and algebraic geometry"

Let $N \cong \mathbb Z^n$ be a free $\mathbb Z$ - module of rank $n$ and $M = \text{Hom}_{\mathbb Z}(N,\mathbb Z)$ be its dual and $T_N = \text{Hom}_{\mathbb Z}(M, \mathbb C^{\times})$ where $\mathbb C^{\times}$ is the multiplicative group of non zero complex numbers.

> (#) **Prove that the set of $\mathbb C$ - algebra homomorphisms from $\mathbb C [M]$ to $\mathbb C$ coincides with $T_N$ where $\mathbb C[M]$ is the group ring of $M$ over $\mathbb C$.**

I have seen the definition of group rings where the group is finite (Dummit Foote). Does the same definition hold for an infinite group? I think understanding the structure of $\mathbb C [M]$ is important to proving (#) because my intuition (given below) doesn't seem to be leading me in the right direction.

1. Now if $m_1, \cdots , m_n$ is a $\mathbb Z$ basis of $M$ then is it true that $\mathbb C [M] = \mathbb C [m_1, \cdots , m_n]$?
2. If 1 is true then since $m_1, \cdots , m_n$ are independent can I say that $\mathbb C[M]$ is a polynomial ring in $n$ variables?
3. If 2 is true then $\text{Hom}_{\mathbb C - \text{alg}}(\mathbb C [m_1, \cdots, m_n],\mathbb C) \cong \mathbb C^n$ but $T_N \cong (\mathbb C ^{\times})^n$ which goes againt (#).

So what am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: It is the same when G is finite , you just make sure any element has only finitely many coefficients non zero, rest all are zero

Comment: The group ring has different characteristics depending on whether or not your group is discrete. If it is not discrete, the group ring is defined as the compactly supported continuous functions on $G$. In the discrete case, the group ring is similar. It's the sets of formal sums with finitely many nonzero terms.

Comment: @BhaskarVashishth then are my statements 1 and 2 correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbb{C}[M]$ will be Laurent polynomials in $x_1,\dots,x_n$.  Algebra homomorphisms to $\mathbb{C}$ are thus determined by sending each $x_i$ to an element of $\mathbb{C}^\times$ and therefore the set of all such homomorphisms is associated with $(\mathbb{C}^\times)^n$

More generally, the group algebra functor is left adjoint to the functor taking an algebra to it's group of units.  The problem you are given is to prove a special case of this property.

Comment: Thank you! Can you give me a hint as to why $\mathbb C[M] = \mathbb C[x_1^{\pm 1}, \cdots, x_n^{\pm 1}]$? It is not clear to me.

Comment: That just follows from the definition.  View $M$ in multiplicative notation as the free abelian group generated by $x_1,\dots,x_n$.  Then $\mathbb{C}[M]$ is the $\mathbb{C}$-vector space with basis $M$ and a certain multiplication (which I won't write, but you know what it is).  Then just see that the multiplication is the same as it is in the space of Laurent polynomials.